# what is the function of window = Tk() in this program as leaving it out gives the same output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, mainloop

```py
from tkinter import *
    
window = Tk()
    
sample = Label(text="some text")
sample.pack()
    
sample2 = Label(text="some other text")
sample2.pack()
    
sample.mainloop()
```

Whats the difference between `sample.mainloop()` and `window.mainloop()`?
Why should window be included in `sample(window, text ="some text")` as the program runs without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sample.mainloop` and `window.mainloop` call the same function internally so they are the same. They both go in a `while True` loop while updating the GUI. They can only exit from the loop when `.quit` or `window.destroy` is called.

This is the code from `tkinter/__init__.py` line 1281:

```py
class Misc:
    ...
    def mainloop(self, n=0):
        """Call the mainloop of Tk."""
        self.tk.mainloop(n)
```

Both `Label` and `Tk` inherit from `Misc` so both of them use that same method. From this:

```py
>>> root = Tk()
>>> root.tk
<_tkinter.tkapp object at 0x00000194116B0A30>
>>> label = Label(root, text="Random text")
>>> label.pack()
>>> label.tk
<_tkinter.tkapp object at 0x00000194116B0A30>
```

You can see that both of the `tk` objects are the same object.

For this line: `sample = Label(text="some text")`, it doesn't matter if you put `window` as the first arg. It only matters if you have multiple windows as tkinter wouldn't know which window you want.

When you have 1 window, tkinter uses that window. This is the code from tkinter/**init**.py line 2251:

```py
class BaseWidget(Misc):
    def __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf={}, kw={}, extra=()):
        ...
        BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)

    def _setup(self, master, cnf):
        ...
            if not master: # if master isn't specified
                ...
                master = _default_root # Use the default window
        self.master = master
```

tkinter `Label` inherits from `Widget` which inherits from `BaseWidget`.

Comment: Saying they stop code execution isn't what happens. No code has stopped executing. It is simply that `mainloop()` doesn't return until the window is destroyed. Code is still executing in the mean time.

Comment: I is what I meant. I will change my answer